# Changing default encoding of Python 3.4?

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8, ascii

I am working on Python 3.4 and I need to change my default encoding but I don't know how to do it. On Python 2.x, it was possible to use the following trick:

```
import sys
reload(sys)  # Reload does the trick!
sys.setdefaultencoding('UTF8')
```

But it does not work on Python 3.x anymore. My default encoding is `US-ASCII` but I need to work with `UTF-8` to export a dict with accents.

Comment: `export PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8` try this in shell.

Comment: It does not seem to be working, i get `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`.

Comment: This is not a python statement, you have to export in `bashrc` file.